# Type controller does not have a default constructor

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Hi friends in webapi using mvc format i created one webapi project here i added autofac resolver to resolve DI(dependency injection) its working fine then in next step i took this dlls and created new project for this i added the dlls now in this project i added one controller but it is showing the error 'x(controller name)' Type controller does not have a default constructor but for this many people given solution for this add new bootstrap class(which contain autofac for di resolve) but i am inherting my old global.asax file from my current global.asax file so i think dont want to add again all the stuff the autofac resolver will get from old dlls so i find many solutions but now luck can any one help me

Note : please ask me incase of any clarity (my english is not good excluse me for this)

Comment: The Mistake I did is Spelling mistake this is if  Controller name is SampleController i am putting SampleContoller (missing r in Controller splleing) thats it now i corrected splleing now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

The Mistake I did is Spelling mistake this is if  Controller name is SampleController i am putting SampleContoller (missing r in Controller splleing) thats it now i corrected splleing now its working fine